# How to run UIAutomation on simulator using Xcode bots - strange behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, ios-ui-automation

I would like to run UIAutomation tests on simulator using Xcode bots. I add this command to past-actions script launched after ARCHIVE phase in xcode:

```
instruments  -t "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate" /Users/ktos/appliation.app -l 10000 -v
```

Xcode bots log followinng error:

```
instruments[6702:507] Recording cancelled : At least one target failed to launch; aborting run
Instruments Trace Error : Error Domain=com.apple.instruments Code=1 "Error Starting Recording" UserInfo=0x7fc053b3a310 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error Starting Recording, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=At least one target failed to launch; aborting run}
Instruments Trace Error : Failed to start trace.
```

When I use exactly the same command in my terminal, on the same computer the instruments runs simulator without any problems. Do you have any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: Somebody on apple developer forum wrote that Xcode bots doesn't support the simulator. I didn't confirm this information.

Comment: So this is not actually as straight forward as it sounds for a handful of reasons. The first reason is because the version of the app created by Archive will not be compatible with the iOS simulator. The archive builds a version for ARCH: Armv7 and the simulator requires ARCH: i386.

Next problem, Bots and OSX Server actually create these hidden users on your machine, and these users are the ones that issue the commands for bots. So part of the issue relates to these hidden users have records of their own simulators.

Comment: Xcode Server will support the simulator. The generated archive will not unless you really monkey with the build settings.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be possible that Instruments is running in the background. Do a $ps -A and check and kill it.